# Typescript is it possible to know the exactly class of an object when using a variable that has a union type?

Tags: typescript

I am studying Typescript, and performing some tests. console.log gives me an object. If Typescript is typed I would expect it know the type of the variable c exactly.

```
interface Car {
  gears: number
}

interface Bike{
  gears: number,
  model: string
}

let c: Bike | Car;

c = {gears : 2};

console.log(typeof c);
```

Answer (score 0):

TS keeps type information only at compile time. Type information is discarded at run time.

Even more, `typeof` is a JS method and as such will operate as JS not TS.

You can look over the return values of `typeof` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#description). TS docs also confirm [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards).

What you probably want is look into [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) as there a lot of ways to to "type checking".

Keep in mind that TS uses `structural typing` as opposed to `nominal typing` (as C#/Java do). This means that 2 object don't need to have the same type, they just need to be compatible enough (this usually means having enough methods/fields to overlap).

Answer (score 0):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a JavaScript operator that gives you the type of a given variable on runtime, while types you define with TypeScript exist only while writing your code and while compiling. On runtime you have only native JavaScript types which are: `Boolean`, `Null`, `Undefined`, `Number`, `BigInt`, `String`, `Symbol` and `Object`.

That has been said, to distinguish between `Car` and `Bike` while using them as a `union` type, a commun way is to have a [discriminator property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions). Like so:

```
interface Car {
  gears: number,
  type:"car"
}

interface Bike{
  gears: number,
  model: string,
  type:"bike"
}

// to show an use case
function foo(bar: Car | Bike ) {
  if(bar.type === "bike"){
    // only here TypeScript would let acces model propriety 
    console.log(bar.model); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a static (compile time) type system.  The code is transpiled to Javascript and so at runtime, there is no type information beyond what JS itself understands.

Because you are using `interface` there is no JS equivilent (likewise with `type`).  *IF* you were to use classes (or objects with a prototype chain) then you would be able to distinguish that runtime using `instanceof`.

```
class Car {
    constructor(public readonly gears: number) {}
}

class Bike{
    constructor(
        public readonly gears: number, 
        public readonly model: string
    ) {}
}

let c: Bike | Car;

c = new Car(2)

console.log(c instanceof Car)
console.log(c instanceof Bike);
```

However, that wouldn't solve the compile time problem of accessing properties on a value that could be either type.

At compile time, if we have a union of `Bike | Car` and try to access a property from `Bike` that doesn't exist on `Car`, we would receive an error.

```
console.log(c.model)
    //        ^^^^^ Property 'model' does not exist on type 'Car'
```

When we use `interface`, we must provide a way to disambiguate the types.  This provides a code path where Typescript understands that a variable's type is narrower than its declaration.  If two types have identical shape, then there is no way to disambiguate, because there is not property that provides that hint.  In your example, `Bike` is different from `Car` in that it has a `model` property, and as such we can write a '[type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)' that provides the necessary hint at both compile time and runtime.

```
function isBike(obj: any): obj is Bike {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && typeof obj.model === 'string'
}
```

We can also write the inverse:

```
function isCar(obj: any): obj is Car {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && typeof obj.model !== 'string'
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
function isCar(obj: any): obj is Car {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && typeof obj.model === undefined
}
```

It's up to you to determine how you discriminate between the types, you could use the value of a property rather than its type or presence of the property, if that fits your use case.

Now we can safely guard any use of `Bike`'s properties, which works both at compile time (it enforces type safety in the narrower code path) and at runtime.

```
if (isBike(c)) {
  console.log(c.model)
}

if (isCar(c)) {
  console.log(c.model)
      //        ^^^^^ Property 'model' does not exist on type 'Car'
}
```

[Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) provide a similar facility.  Type predicates rely on the implementation of the predicate being correct - if your predicate returns true then Typescript just accepts that you are right for the remainder of the affected code path.  This can be tricky when refactoring as you might add properties to the `interface` or `type` and forget to update the predicate, potentially allowing a variable to be misidentified.  But it has the advantage that you can have type unions where there is no common property that acts as a discriminator.